# Sending large Files to external system

Tags: rest-api, encryption, connect-api, aws

From Salesforce, I am sending files to AWS Server. I am able to successfully achieve it if the file is under 3 to 4 MB. When I try with more than 6 to 7 MB, the file is getting reached to the AWS server but the file size under 1MB. I am encrypting the file before appending it to the JSON Body.

The next issue is, encrypting the file. We can only encrypt the data which is under 1 MB. "Thrown if the data is greater than 1 MB. For decryption, 1048608 bytes are allowed for the initialization vector header, plus any additional padding the encryption added to align to block size". How can we overcome these issues while sending data to AWS server.

After some high-level research, I come to know that it can only be achieved only with these methods.

1. Chatter API
2. Using Some middleware or some other server to store the files(Like Heroku)
3. Some other 3rd party appexchange products.

Is there any other way to accomplish the large file data transfer?

NOTE: Large files typically refers to more than 10 MB.

Kindly let me know if you have worked on such a scenario and if you have the best solution than the above-mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Sending files from Apex will not allow you because of Heap space. Since you mentioned encryption as well, so definitely some heap space is consumed by those additional variables. One quick hack is to send the data from JS front(from apex you can parse files partly and join in the JS), but again this needs human intervention.

How about, if you have any middle-ware service or any service at the AWS, they can use that to download the file(which is possible with GBs as well).

Since Evergreen functions(check its availability before considering) launched by Salesforce, you can try those with AWS Lambda.

Reference to Evergreen functions -

1. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/introducing-salesforce-evergreen.html
2. https://www.cloudgalacticos.co.uk/2019/11/26/salesforce-evergreen-a-game-changer-for-salesforce-developers/
3. https://www.anup.io/2020/03/03/possibilities-with-salesforce-evergreen/

Comment: We are using AWS Lamda as well and API gateway to perform some business logics. In AWS, things are working as expected. But sending a large file is a huge block on salesforce end. If you can explain little bit more on the AWS Lamda and SF Evergreen, that would be helpful.

Comment: Since you mentioned AWS is being used. What you can do is, you can generate a file URL(ContentDistribution object at salesforce level) and store it on Content Document(file), which you can use to download the file. Now since you're using lambda, there you can encrypt it and proceed further. 

Base idea is, you can do query and execute the download URL and now since you got the downloaded file, you can encrypt it in AWS side. Regarding Evergreen functions ( its a theory for me atleast, not tried), we can write some node script(also some other scripts) to perform same operation

Comment: Actually, the idea is to store all the files in AWS and retrieve it when the page gets loaded. So we don't need to store any files inside salesforce. I think the given solution needs to store the files in SF by utilizing the ContentDistribution technique. 

Even though I generate the public URL and pass it to the AWS system. How does the Lambda or API gateway can download or process the content?

Comment: there're many ways to download depending on the technology you can choose. E.g. the curl command can be the easiest one here. With python/node also there are different ways to download files. Regarding storage, yes it's fine to store in AWS/SFDC. I'm suggesting a way to send files from Salesforce to AWS. For AWS to SFDC, you can have Connect API, which allows 2Gb files.